# Resizing causes errors?

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, tkinter

I'm Learning, slowly! part of the code below is from a question on here about resizing objects in a tkinter canvas. anyway my aim is to make starting grid lights, as i learn more i will add the ability of starting and stopping it with buttons or keys, but for now i just want to get it working visually.
I want it to fit perfect to any screen i run it on without changing the code etc, but when i re size the window it starts adding circles in different places and its getting me very confused.

```
import tkinter
import time

class ReDraw():
    def __init__(self):
        self._tk = tkinter.Tk()

        self._myframe = tkinter.Frame(master = self._tk)
        self._myframe.grid(row = 0, column = 0, sticky = tkinter.NSEW)

        self._mycanvas = tkinter.Canvas(master = self._tk, width = 850, height = 400, bg = 'grey', highlightthickness = 0)
        self._mycanvas.grid(row = 0, column = 0, sticky = tkinter.NSEW) 

        self._mycanvas.bind("<Configure>", self._on_resize)

        self._tk.rowconfigure(0, weight = 1)
        self._tk.columnconfigure(0, weight = 1)

        self.fracX = 1
        self.fracY = 1

        self._oval1 = self._mycanvas.create_oval(50*self.fracX,50*self.fracY,160*self.fracX,160*self.fracY, fill="black", tags = 'oval1')
        self._oval2 = self._mycanvas.create_oval(210*self.fracX,50*self.fracY,320*self.fracX,160*self.fracY, fill="black", tags = 'oval2')
        self._oval3 = self._mycanvas.create_oval(370*self.fracX,50*self.fracY,480*self.fracX,160*self.fracY, fill="black", tags = 'oval3')
        self._oval4 = self._mycanvas.create_oval(530*self.fracX,50*self.fracY,640*self.fracX,160*self.fracY, fill="black", tags = 'oval4')
        self._oval5 = self._mycanvas.create_oval(690*self.fracX,50*self.fracY,800*self.fracX,160*self.fracY, fill="black", tags = 'oval5')

    def _on_resize(self, event):
        self._mycanvas.delete(tkinter.ALL)
        self.fracX = event.width/850
        self.fracY = event.height/400
        self._oval1 = self._mycanvas.create_oval(50*self.fracX,50*self.fracY,160*self.fracX,160*self.fracY, fill="black", tags = 'oval1')
        self._oval2 = self._mycanvas.create_oval(210*self.fracX,50*self.fracY,320*self.fracX,160*self.fracY, fill="black", tags = 'oval2')
        self._oval3 = self._mycanvas.create_oval(370*self.fracX,50*self.fracY,480*self.fracX,160*self.fracY, fill="black", tags = 'oval3')
        self._oval4 = self._mycanvas.create_oval(530*self.fracX,50*self.fracY,640*self.fracX,160*self.fracY, fill="black", tags = 'oval4')
        self._oval5 = self._mycanvas.create_oval(690*self.fracX,50*self.fracY,800*self.fracX,160*self.fracY, fill="black", tags = 'oval5')

def main():
    canvas = ReDraw()
    # Some widgets to the canvas
    def red0(a):
        for i in range(a):
            canvas._mycanvas.delete('oval1')
            canvas._oval1 = canvas._mycanvas.create_oval(50*canvas.fracX,50*canvas.fracY,160*canvas.fracX,160*canvas.fracY, fill="red", tags = 'oval1') 
            canvas._tk.update()
            time.sleep(0.05)            
    def red1(a):
        for i in range(a):
            canvas._mycanvas.delete('oval1')
            canvas._oval1 = canvas._mycanvas.create_oval(50*canvas.fracX,50*canvas.fracY,160*canvas.fracX,160*canvas.fracY, fill="red", tags = 'oval1') 
            canvas._mycanvas.delete('oval2')
            canvas._oval2 = canvas._mycanvas.create_oval(210*canvas.fracX,50*canvas.fracY,320*canvas.fracX,160*canvas.fracY, fill="red", tags = 'oval2') 
            canvas._tk.update()
            time.sleep(0.05)                
    def red2(a):
        for i in range(a):
            canvas._mycanvas.delete('oval1')
            canvas._oval1 = canvas._mycanvas.create_oval(50*canvas.fracX,50*canvas.fracY,160*canvas.fracX,160*canvas.fracY, fill="red", tags = 'oval1') 
            canvas._mycanvas.delete('oval2')
            canvas._oval2 = canvas._mycanvas.create_oval(210*canvas.fracX,50*canvas.fracY,320*canvas.fracX,160*canvas.fracY, fill="red", tags = 'oval2') 
            canvas._mycanvas.delete('oval3')
            canvas._oval3 = canvas._mycanvas.create_oval(370*canvas.fracX,50*canvas.fracY,480*canvas.fracX,160*canvas.fracY, fill="red", tags = 'oval3') 
            canvas._tk.update()
            time.sleep(0.05)                 
    def red3(a):
        for i in range(a):
            canvas._mycanvas.delete('oval1')
            canvas._oval1 = canvas._mycanvas.create_oval(50*canvas.fracX,50*canvas.fracY,160*canvas.fracX,160*canvas.fracY, fill="red", tags = 'oval1') 
            canvas._mycanvas.delete('oval2')
            canvas._oval2 = canvas._mycanvas.create_oval(210*canvas.fracX,50*canvas.fracY,320*canvas.fracX,160*canvas.fracY, fill="red", tags = 'oval2') 
            canvas._mycanvas.delete('oval3')
            canvas._oval3 = canvas._mycanvas.create_oval(370*canvas.fracX,50*canvas.fracY,480*canvas.fracX,160*canvas.fracY, fill="red", tags = 'oval3') 
            canvas._mycanvas.delete('oval4')
            canvas._oval4 = canvas._mycanvas.create_oval(530*canvas.fracX,50*canvas.fracY,640*canvas.fracX,160*canvas.fracY, fill="red", tags = 'oval4') 
            canvas._tk.update()
            time.sleep(0.05)                
    def red4(a):
        for i in range(a):
            canvas._mycanvas.delete('oval5')
            canvas._oval5 = canvas._mycanvas.create_oval(690*canvas.fracX,50*canvas.fracY,800*canvas.fracX,160*canvas.fracY, fill="red", tags = 'oval5') 
            canvas._tk.update()
            time.sleep(0.05)     
    def green(a):
        for i in range(a):
            canvas._mycanvas.delete(tkinter.ALL)
            canvas._oval1 = canvas._mycanvas.create_oval(50*canvas.fracX,50*canvas.fracY,160*canvas.fracX,160*canvas.fracY, fill="green", tags = 'oval1')
            canvas._oval2 = canvas._mycanvas.create_oval(210*canvas.fracX,50*canvas.fracY,320*canvas.fracX,160*canvas.fracY, fill="green", tags = 'oval2')
            canvas._oval3 = canvas._mycanvas.create_oval(370*canvas.fracX,50*canvas.fracY,480*canvas.fracX,160*canvas.fracY, fill="green", tags = 'oval3')
            canvas._oval4 = canvas._mycanvas.create_oval(530*canvas.fracX,50*canvas.fracY,640*canvas.fracX,160*canvas.fracY, fill="green", tags = 'oval4')
            canvas._oval5 = canvas._mycanvas.create_oval(690*canvas.fracX,50*canvas.fracY,800*canvas.fracX,160*canvas.fracY, fill="green", tags = 'oval5')
            canvas._tk.update()
            time.sleep(0.05)
    def amber(a):
        for i in range(a):
            canvas._mycanvas.delete(tkinter.ALL)
            canvas._oval1 = canvas._mycanvas.create_oval(50*canvas.fracX,50*canvas.fracY,160*canvas.fracX,160*canvas.fracY, fill="yellow", tags = 'oval1')
            canvas._oval2 = canvas._mycanvas.create_oval(210*canvas.fracX,50*canvas.fracY,320*canvas.fracX,160*canvas.fracY, fill="yellow", tags = 'oval2')
            canvas._oval3 = canvas._mycanvas.create_oval(370*canvas.fracX,50*canvas.fracY,480*canvas.fracX,160*canvas.fracY, fill="yellow", tags = 'oval3')
            canvas._oval4 = canvas._mycanvas.create_oval(530*canvas.fracX,50*canvas.fracY,640*canvas.fracX,160*canvas.fracY, fill="yellow", tags = 'oval4')
            canvas._oval5 = canvas._mycanvas.create_oval(690*canvas.fracX,50*canvas.fracY,800*canvas.fracX,160*canvas.fracY, fill="yellow", tags = 'oval5')
            canvas._tk.update()
            time.sleep(0.05)
    def lights1(a):
        for i in range(a):
            canvas._mycanvas.delete(tkinter.ALL)
            canvas._oval1 = canvas._mycanvas.create_oval(50*canvas.fracX,50*canvas.fracY,160*canvas.fracX,160*canvas.fracY, fill="black", tags = 'oval1')
            canvas._oval2 = canvas._mycanvas.create_oval(210*canvas.fracX,50*canvas.fracY,320*canvas.fracX,160*canvas.fracY, fill="black", tags = 'oval2')
            canvas._oval3 = canvas._mycanvas.create_oval(370*canvas.fracX,50*canvas.fracY,480*canvas.fracX,160*canvas.fracY, fill="black", tags = 'oval3')
            canvas._oval4 = canvas._mycanvas.create_oval(530*canvas.fracX,50*canvas.fracY,640*canvas.fracX,160*canvas.fracY, fill="black", tags = 'oval4')
            canvas._oval5 = canvas._mycanvas.create_oval(690*canvas.fracX,50*canvas.fracY,800*canvas.fracX,160*canvas.fracY, fill="black", tags = 'oval5')
            canvas._tk.update()
            time.sleep(0.05)
    def lights():
        canvas._mycanvas.delete(tkinter.ALL)
        canvas._oval1 = canvas._mycanvas.create_oval(50*canvas.fracX,50*canvas.fracY,160*canvas.fracX,160*canvas.fracY, fill="black", tags = 'oval1')
        canvas._oval2 = canvas._mycanvas.create_oval(210*canvas.fracX,50*canvas.fracY,320*canvas.fracX,160*canvas.fracY, fill="black", tags = 'oval2')
        canvas._oval3 = canvas._mycanvas.create_oval(370*canvas.fracX,50*canvas.fracY,480*canvas.fracX,160*canvas.fracY, fill="black", tags = 'oval3')
        canvas._oval4 = canvas._mycanvas.create_oval(530*canvas.fracX,50*canvas.fracY,640*canvas.fracX,160*canvas.fracY, fill="black", tags = 'oval4')
        canvas._oval5 = canvas._mycanvas.create_oval(690*canvas.fracX,50*canvas.fracY,800*canvas.fracX,160*canvas.fracY, fill="black", tags = 'oval5')
        canvas._tk.update()

    # tag all of the drawn widgets
    def flashing():
        global flag
        flag=1
        while flag:
            if flag == 1:

                lights1(9)
                amber(10)
                lights()
    def stop():
        global flag
        flag = 2
        while flag:
            if flag == 2:
                lights()

    def start():
        global flag
        flag = 3
        while flag:
            if flag == 3:
                lights()
                red0(30)
                red1(30)
                red2(30)
                red3(30)
                red4(30)
                green(30)
                lights()
                break


    canvas._but1 = tkinter.Button(text="start", command=start)
    canvas._but1.grid(row = 2, column = 0, sticky="w")
    canvas._but2 = tkinter.Button(text="amber", command=flashing)
    canvas._but2.grid(row = 2, sticky="w", padx=(80))
    canvas._but1 = tkinter.Button(text="stop", command=stop)
    canvas._but1.grid(row = 2, column = 0, sticky="w", padx=(40))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Re re edited sorted most of the problems but still think it's rather messy still getting loads of errors

Comment: Stop drawing when you resize.

Comment: Hi, Please can you explain how. Thank you.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
import tkinter
import time

class ReDraw():
    def __init__(self):
        self._tk = tkinter.Tk()

        self._myframe = tkinter.Frame(master = self._tk)
        self._myframe.grid(row = 0, column = 0, sticky = tkinter.NSEW)

        self._mycanvas = tkinter.Canvas(master = self._tk, width = 850, height = 400, bg = 'grey', highlightthickness = 0)
        self._mycanvas.grid(row = 0, column = 0, sticky = tkinter.NSEW) 

        self._mycanvas.bind("<Configure>", self._on_resize)

        self._tk.rowconfigure(0, weight = 1)
        self._tk.columnconfigure(0, weight = 1)

        self.fracX = 1
        self.fracY = 1

        self._oval1 = self._mycanvas.create_oval(50*self.fracX,50*self.fracY,160*self.fracX,160*self.fracY, fill="black", tags = 'oval1')
        self._oval2 = self._mycanvas.create_oval(210*self.fracX,50*self.fracY,320*self.fracX,160*self.fracY, fill="black", tags = 'oval2')
        self._oval3 = self._mycanvas.create_oval(370*self.fracX,50*self.fracY,480*self.fracX,160*self.fracY, fill="black", tags = 'oval3')
        self._oval4 = self._mycanvas.create_oval(530*self.fracX,50*self.fracY,640*self.fracX,160*self.fracY, fill="black", tags = 'oval4')
        self._oval5 = self._mycanvas.create_oval(690*self.fracX,50*self.fracY,800*self.fracX,160*self.fracY, fill="black", tags = 'oval5')

    def _on_resize(self, event):
        self._mycanvas.delete(tkinter.ALL)
        self.fracX = event.width/850
        self.fracY = event.height/400
        self._oval1 = self._mycanvas.create_oval(50*self.fracX,50*self.fracY,160*self.fracX,160*self.fracY, fill="black", tags = 'oval1')
        self._oval2 = self._mycanvas.create_oval(210*self.fracX,50*self.fracY,320*self.fracX,160*self.fracY, fill="black", tags = 'oval2')
        self._oval3 = self._mycanvas.create_oval(370*self.fracX,50*self.fracY,480*self.fracX,160*self.fracY, fill="black", tags = 'oval3')
        self._oval4 = self._mycanvas.create_oval(530*self.fracX,50*self.fracY,640*self.fracX,160*self.fracY, fill="black", tags = 'oval4')
        self._oval5 = self._mycanvas.create_oval(690*self.fracX,50*self.fracY,800*self.fracX,160*self.fracY, fill="black", tags = 'oval5')

def main():
    canvas = ReDraw()
    # Some widgets to the canvas
    def red0(a):
        for i in range(a):
            canvas._mycanvas.delete('oval1')
            canvas._oval1 = canvas._mycanvas.create_oval(50*canvas.fracX,50*canvas.fracY,160*canvas.fracX,160*canvas.fracY, fill="red", tags = 'oval1') 
            canvas._tk.update()
            time.sleep(0.05)            
    def red1(a):
        for i in range(a):
            canvas._mycanvas.delete('oval1')
            canvas._oval1 = canvas._mycanvas.create_oval(50*canvas.fracX,50*canvas.fracY,160*canvas.fracX,160*canvas.fracY, fill="red", tags = 'oval1') 
            canvas._mycanvas.delete('oval2')
            canvas._oval2 = canvas._mycanvas.create_oval(210*canvas.fracX,50*canvas.fracY,320*canvas.fracX,160*canvas.fracY, fill="red", tags = 'oval2') 
            canvas._tk.update()
            time.sleep(0.05)                
    def red2(a):
        for i in range(a):
            canvas._mycanvas.delete('oval1')
            canvas._oval1 = canvas._mycanvas.create_oval(50*canvas.fracX,50*canvas.fracY,160*canvas.fracX,160*canvas.fracY, fill="red", tags = 'oval1') 
            canvas._mycanvas.delete('oval2')
            canvas._oval2 = canvas._mycanvas.create_oval(210*canvas.fracX,50*canvas.fracY,320*canvas.fracX,160*canvas.fracY, fill="red", tags = 'oval2') 
            canvas._mycanvas.delete('oval3')
            canvas._oval3 = canvas._mycanvas.create_oval(370*canvas.fracX,50*canvas.fracY,480*canvas.fracX,160*canvas.fracY, fill="red", tags = 'oval3') 
            canvas._tk.update()
            time.sleep(0.05)                 
    def red3(a):
        for i in range(a):
            canvas._mycanvas.delete('oval1')
            canvas._oval1 = canvas._mycanvas.create_oval(50*canvas.fracX,50*canvas.fracY,160*canvas.fracX,160*canvas.fracY, fill="red", tags = 'oval1') 
            canvas._mycanvas.delete('oval2')
            canvas._oval2 = canvas._mycanvas.create_oval(210*canvas.fracX,50*canvas.fracY,320*canvas.fracX,160*canvas.fracY, fill="red", tags = 'oval2') 
            canvas._mycanvas.delete('oval3')
            canvas._oval3 = canvas._mycanvas.create_oval(370*canvas.fracX,50*canvas.fracY,480*canvas.fracX,160*canvas.fracY, fill="red", tags = 'oval3') 
            canvas._mycanvas.delete('oval4')
            canvas._oval4 = canvas._mycanvas.create_oval(530*canvas.fracX,50*canvas.fracY,640*canvas.fracX,160*canvas.fracY, fill="red", tags = 'oval4') 
            canvas._tk.update()
            time.sleep(0.05)                
    def red4(a):
        for i in range(a):
            canvas._mycanvas.delete('oval5')
            canvas._oval5 = canvas._mycanvas.create_oval(690*canvas.fracX,50*canvas.fracY,800*canvas.fracX,160*canvas.fracY, fill="red", tags = 'oval5') 
            canvas._tk.update()
            time.sleep(0.05)     
    def green(a):
        for i in range(a):
            canvas._mycanvas.delete(tkinter.ALL)
            canvas._oval1 = canvas._mycanvas.create_oval(50*canvas.fracX,50*canvas.fracY,160*canvas.fracX,160*canvas.fracY, fill="green", tags = 'oval1')
            canvas._oval2 = canvas._mycanvas.create_oval(210*canvas.fracX,50*canvas.fracY,320*canvas.fracX,160*canvas.fracY, fill="green", tags = 'oval2')
            canvas._oval3 = canvas._mycanvas.create_oval(370*canvas.fracX,50*canvas.fracY,480*canvas.fracX,160*canvas.fracY, fill="green", tags = 'oval3')
            canvas._oval4 = canvas._mycanvas.create_oval(530*canvas.fracX,50*canvas.fracY,640*canvas.fracX,160*canvas.fracY, fill="green", tags = 'oval4')
            canvas._oval5 = canvas._mycanvas.create_oval(690*canvas.fracX,50*canvas.fracY,800*canvas.fracX,160*canvas.fracY, fill="green", tags = 'oval5')
            canvas._tk.update()
            time.sleep(0.05)
    def lights():
        canvas._mycanvas.delete(tkinter.ALL)
        canvas._oval1 = canvas._mycanvas.create_oval(50*canvas.fracX,50*canvas.fracY,160*canvas.fracX,160*canvas.fracY, fill="black", tags = 'oval1')
        canvas._oval2 = canvas._mycanvas.create_oval(210*canvas.fracX,50*canvas.fracY,320*canvas.fracX,160*canvas.fracY, fill="black", tags = 'oval2')
        canvas._oval3 = canvas._mycanvas.create_oval(370*canvas.fracX,50*canvas.fracY,480*canvas.fracX,160*canvas.fracY, fill="black", tags = 'oval3')
        canvas._oval4 = canvas._mycanvas.create_oval(530*canvas.fracX,50*canvas.fracY,640*canvas.fracX,160*canvas.fracY, fill="black", tags = 'oval4')
        canvas._oval5 = canvas._mycanvas.create_oval(690*canvas.fracX,50*canvas.fracY,800*canvas.fracX,160*canvas.fracY, fill="black", tags = 'oval5')
        canvas._tk.update()

    # tag all of the drawn widgets
    for i in range(20):
        lights()
        red0(30)
        red1(30)
        red2(30)
        red3(30)
        red4(30)
        green(30)
        lights()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

So I just fix your code and it works now, just check it out! The problem about your code is even though you resized the canvas in your class ***ResizingCanvas*** (which worked fine), in your ***main()*** function, you still keep creating new ovals inside your resized canvas at specific places.

Moreover, I think it is better if you create your whole tkinter application as an object since you can control your object more easily and making methods or attributes to get the data. Therefore, in my fixed code, I put the whole `tkinter.Tk()` object into my **ReDraw()** class. Then, I create ovals inside that class and put tags for each of them, so I can easily delete what ovals I want later on in the ***main()*** function. Just look up the code and ask me if you don't understand it!

P/S: I'd prefer you using `.grid()` instead of `.pack()` since it is a better tool for resizing windows and also easier to arrange the interface!

Comment: Wow! Thank you so much Tim! I'm just looking at it now, yours is quite a bit more complex than my code. although i understand what's going on, it's defiantly a little above my skills. thank you again for taking the time to show and explain to me, i'll defiantly have a play around with it to fully grasp your example.

Comment: hello I'm trying to add a button to start and stop the lights but i cant seem to do it with your code i can get it to work with my old code, can you explain abit more in depth please

Comment: Okay so I've been playing around and I have managed to add a start and stop button, Yay!. but there's a few problems... 1. i cant position the buttons next to each other with grid. 2. I cant stop it. and 3. I get alot of error in the shell. I've edited my code to include the buttons etc. cheers